# Need to export csv exactly as it was imported

Tags: python, pandas

I need to read in a csv and export an exact replica. I have read it in and can export it with the same information, however the result is slightly different. The original file is on a single line while my new export is on multiple lines.

I've read in the file with pd.read_csv and have export it with pd.to_csv

## read in file

## Need to sperate by '|', also names are column names

```
csv1 = pd.read_csv(r'\path\csv1.txt', sep = '|', header = 0)
```

## export to new file called 'csv2.txt' where it is identical to csv1

```
csv1.to_csv(r'\path\csv2.txt', sep = '|', index = False)
```

No error messages. CSV1 is one line deliminated by '|', my result is 4 lines with each dataframe column separated by '|'

When I open CSV1 it looks like:

```
john|mary|joe34|25|332|21|4321|42|25
```

When I open CSV2 it looks like:

```
john|34|32|21
mary|25|21|42
joe|3|43|25
```

Reading in csv2 like I did for csv1 yields the same results. However, why is the txt file look different when I open them?

Comment: Should it be `sep='\|'` in `read_csv`?

Comment: `cp \path\csv1.txt \path\csv2.txt`

Comment: @QuangHoang `|` is not a special character in Python strings.  Why would you escape it?

Comment: @JohnGordon It is a special character in regex pattern, which could be used in `sep` option.

Comment: Can you post an example of the csv1.txt file? Also an example of csv2.txt would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

```
import csv

read_file = 'filename';

csv.register_dialect('myDialect', delimiter='|', quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)

myFile = open('write_file.txt', 'w')  
with myFile:  
   writer = csv.writer(myFile, dialect='myDialect')

   writer.writerows(read_file)
```

Comment: Although this code snippet may answer the question, including an explanation of *why* and *how* it helps solve the problem improves the quality and longevity of your answer. See ["How do I write a good answer?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).